# Deduce the Nested Interval Property from MCT?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be an increasing sequence, $b_n$ be a decreasing sequence, and assume that $a_n < b_n, \space \forall n \in N$.  Show that $\lim(a_n) ≤ \lim(b_n)$, and thereby deduce the Nested Intervals Property from the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You have $a_n \le a_{m+n} < b_{m+n} < b_m$, so $a_n < b_m$ for any integers
$m$ and $n$.  Can you do the rest?